# How do I delete old backup files?

Tags: deja-dup

I have instructed DejaDup to keep one-week of backup files. Now it is passed more than a month and my backup storage is fed up with old backups. Is there a way to instruct DejaDup to delete old backups without reaching the storage limit? Can I detele them manually?

Answer (score 15):

Additionally you can prune the backup yourself. What I did is to use:

```
duplicity remove-all-but-n-full 1 --force scp://mylogin@myserver/path_to_backup
```

from command line. Just use the information you used to create your backups from the Ubuntu GUI.

Comment: One caveat is the `path_to_backup` is relative to `mylogin` home directory.  I tried `sftp://mylogin@myserver/usr/home/mylogin/backup` and it created new folder `/usr/home/mylogin/usr/home/mylogin/backup` which of course is empty and it say that it cannot find any backups here. :)

Comment: /usr/home ? Is't that a typo by any chance? Usually home folders are in /home on root.

Comment: No. In FreeBSD home folder at /usr/home and /home is just a symlink.

Comment: In this case I think that the path is always relative to your home and you should use sftp://mylogin@myserver/backup

Comment: Hm... That is what i said in my first comment. :)

But it was surprise to me because all other utils that I used before (git for example) use absolute paths in their urls, regardless of what login is part of the url.

Answer (score 8):

You can use the Dconf app from Ubuntu Store to modify setting at path org.gnome.DejaDup, key name delete-after. It's set to the number of days to keep backup files on backup location.

Or from terminal. For example, to set it to 60 days from the command line, run:

```
gsettings set org.gnome.DejaDup delete-after 60
```

Comment: This is correct.  However, opening the "Backups" GUI will sometimes cause this setting to revert to "At least 6 months" when the app is closed again.

Comment: I really like this approach. Thanks man!

Answer (score 6):

The answer of https://askubuntu.com/a/94288/676490 for a local backup:

```
duplicity remove-all-but-n-full 1 --force file:///home/username/deja-dup
```

Answer (score 4):

Deja-dup does not yet supply a way of removing old backups, you should also not delete some of the files, that will leave probably your backups without a start file and renders them invalid. Remove them all and start over is an option but thats not what you want I think.

Deja-dup keeps backups for the specified time or until the backup space is full, it will them manage your backups accordingly, a solution for your problem might just be enable quotas for the backup drive and don't let it take all the space available or change the backup frequency, once a week if you edit many files or are always copying / moving files will leave you with a very large backup image.

Comment: Thnaks for the answer Bruno. I am backing up over ssh into a folder on a remote server. I don't want the backup growing until the server is full! And I don't have access to set up a disk quota. This is very bad. I will change the backup system...

Comment: You can use the backend from deja-up duplicity to do exactly the same duplicity does but with more options, to understand what is happening in a terminal type `deja-dup --backup` and check the messages one of those is your actual duplicity backup command and it can be customized.

Comment: The customization you are looking for it the "keep x rev from the files" where x will be the number of copies available to restore, you can set that for example 30, so more then 30 rev of a file and duplicity deletes the backup itself. Look also `man duplicity` for all the options.

Comment: Bruno you are right, the switch I am looking for that. Is it available only from terminal, no GUI option for it?